# Im trying to work exec function with await and math library but it doesnt

Tags: python, discord

```
@client.command()
async def evlF(ctx,arg):
   exec("await ctx.send({arg})")
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: And how ı can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the leading `f` for f-string literals huh?

```
async def evlF(ctx,arg):
   exec(f"await ctx.send({arg})")
```

That's ok but do you really need `exec()`?

```
async def evlF(ctx,arg):
   await ctx.send(arg)
```

Comment: I wrote "f" actually, this is not the point.arg is a function like "print"